# SQL Server : how to cross join table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL Server tables as follows and need to perform join to produce results as below.

**Custorder**:

```
itemcode   orderqty
-------------------
item001      10
item003      30
item004      50
```

**manufactured**:

```
itemcode    manuqty
--------------------
item001       100
item002       200
item004       300
```

How can I join these two tables to produce

```
itemcode    orderqty    manuqty  
---------------------------------
item001        10         100
item002       NULL        200
item003        30         NULL
item004        50         300
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4):

you can use full outer join for this.

```
SELECT  ISNULL(co.itemcode, ma.itemcode) itemcode ,
        orderqty ,
        manuqty
FROM    custorder co
        FULL OUTER JOIN manufactured ma ON co.itemcode = ma.itemcode
```

another option you have is to use a query to build your itemcode list from both tables and join to it to get your result.. this could result in a very slow query if you have a lot of records.. Ideally you would have a table similar to `inventory (itemid int, itemcode varchar)` and you would use that table to outer join to the others..

```
;WITH items AS (
    --get distinct itemcodes from both tables
    SELECT itemcode FROM custorder
    UNION
    SELECT itemcode FROM manufactured  
)
SELECT  i.itemcode,
        co.orderqty,
        ma.manuqty
FROM    custorder co
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN items i ON i.itemcode = co.itemcode
        LEFT OUTER JOIN manufactured ma ON i.itemcode = ma.itemcode
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the phrase "Cross-Join" is used in DB community to refer to a join that produces what is called a "Cartesian product". For e.g., the alphabet cross-joined with itself would produce AA, AB, AC, AD...AZ, BA, BB, BC, etc.

What you want is just a regular join:

```
 Select coalesce(co.itemcode, m.itemcode) itemCode, 
    co.orderqty, m.manuqty
 From custorder co
    full join manufactured m 
        on m.itemcode = co.itemcode
```

Comment: @Charless Bretana i tested the code only gives item001 10 100 and item004 50 300, the other two items are missing

Comment: then you want outer join, in this case a `full` [outer] `join`.  I edited my answer to fix.

Comment: thanks bro, just wondering if there no other way than using coalesce (isnull etc) or other type of join method?

Comment: Well, this is the simplest way.  There is another more convoluted way, by taking a union of the distinct ItemCodes from both tables, and then, for each itemcode in that unioned output, adding the Qty columns from thye individual tables in correlated subqueries, but this is much more complex.